# syntax error: unexpected literal "http://localhost:8080/cargautil.txt", expecting comma or ) En Go

Tags: go

Tengo este código, pero al compilar me sale este error: syntax error: unexpected literal "http://localhost:8080/cargautil.txt", expecting comma or )  cuál podría ser una solución?

Cómo podría arreglar el error que me sale?

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "io/ioutil"
    "net/http"
)



func main() {

    co := Downloadedcode(datos "http://localhost:8080/cargautil.txt")
    fmt.Println(co)
}

func Downloadedcode(datos string)string{
    link,err := http.Get(datos)
    Capturaerror(err)

    reqBody,err := ioutil.ReadAll(link.Body)
    Capturaerror(err)
    return string(reqBody)

}

func Capturaerror(e error) {
    if e != nil {
        fmt.Println(e)
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Aquí estaba el error

```
co := Downloadedcode(**datos** "http://localhost:8080/cargautil.txt")
```

No era necesario volver a llamar datos.